# Is it possible to make brace expansion copy the result of globing to an nonexistent file

Tags: bash, zsh

In Bash, brace expansion doesn't copy the result of globing to an nonexistent file.

For example, in the current directory, there is a file named `1.epub`, and I would like to convert it to a pdf file with the same filename except extension. The pdf file `1.pdf` doesn't exist yet.

```
$ ebook-convert *.{epub,pdf}
```

and the resulted file is `*.pdf`.

In Bash, do I need to extract the base name of the epub file to a variable firstly, and then use the value of that variable to name the pdf file?

Is there a more elegant solution, inside Bash or in other shells?

Answer (score 10):

The shell technique uses a loop.

In sh, and other sh-like shells such as bash or zsh:

```bash
for f in *.epub; do
  ebook-convert -- "$f" "${f%.epub}.pdf"
done
```

In zsh, that can be shortened to:

```
for f (*.epub(N)) ebook-convert -- $f $f:r.pdf
```

The `N`ullglob glob qualifier also avoids the error if there's no matching file. bash has no equivalent but you can set the `nullglob` option globally beforehand; in ksh93, you can also use `for f in ~(N)*.epub; do...`

You might have a `rename` program installed: `man 1 rename`

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane!

Answer (score 6):

The `zmv` utility in `zsh` can be used with any command, and works well with patterns like this:

```bash
autoload zmv
zmv -Wn -p ebook-convert '*.epub' '*.pdf'
```

The `-n` is for a dry run - remove it when you're comfortable with the result.

This can be even shorter as an alias, with this in `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
autoload zmv
alias ebc='noglob zmv -W -p ebook-convert '
```

Now the command line is simply:

```
ebc *.epub *.pdf
```

Example:

```bash
> ls *.epub
1.epub b2.epub
> ebc -n *.epub *.pdf
ebook-convert -- 1.epub 1.pdf
ebook-convert -- b2.epub b2.pdf
```

More options for using `zmv` are described in the [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv).

Comment: The trailing space in that alias is not particularly useful. It mean aliases are expanded in the word after `ebc` which doesn't really make sense to do here.

Answer (score 6):

> In Bash, brace expansion doesn't copy the result of globing to an nonexistent file.

Indeed not, by specification.  Brace expansion is the first expansion Bash performs on each command, and pathname expansion is the last.  Thus, when presented with your command

> ```
> ebook-convert *.{epub,pdf}
> ```

, bash first performs brace expansion to to get

```
ebook-convert *.epub *.pdf
```

, and it only later performs pathname expansion -- separately for each pattern.  Unless the nullglob shell option is set, a glob a pattern that does not match any files expands to itself, so you cannot use this approach to generate the name of a .pdf file that does not already exist.

What's more, if there is more than one `.epub` file in the working directory, or if there is a `.pdf` different than the one you want to write, then that command will expand to something potentially destructive.

> In Bash, do I need to extract the base name of the epub file to a variable firstly, and then use the value of that variable to name the pdf file?

You could avoid actually storing the EPUB name in a variable, but you do need to find the epub name first, then apply a transformation to it separately, especially if you're going to use a glob to identify the EPUB.

I would suggest a shell function:

```
epub_to_pdf() {
  for epub; do
    ebook-convert "${epub}" "${epub%.epub}.pdf"
  done
}
```

Having defined that, you need only to designate the EPUB to it, not the corresponding PDF:

```
epub_to_pdf *.epub
```

That will handle multiple EPUBs appropriately, too.  You presumably do not want to define the function every time, but you could put the definition in your `.bashrc` to ensure that it's always available to you.

Answer (score 5):

The "elegant solution" is pattern rules in GNU Make. If we have a `Makefile` like this:

```
%.pdf: %.epub
        ebook-convert -- $^ $@
```

then you can just

```
$ make 1.pdf
```

GNU Make will see that `1.pdf` doesn't exist and that it matches the left side of the pattern rule we wrote, `%.pdf`. It will instantiate the pattern and see that the right side produces `1.epub`.  Then it will run the command `ebook-convert 1.epub 1.pdf`.

If we run that command again, it will go through the same pattern matching and then see that `1.pdf` is newer than `1.epub` and report that `1.pdf` is up-to-date.

Comment: I don't think that `--` is a worthwhile improvement here. Firstly, Make does not support filenames with spaces at all, so we cannot make a Makefile completely robust for arbitrary filenames. Makefiles are almost never released as stand-alone scripts to be used with arbitrarily named files that do not accompany them.  The same people making the Makefile also control the naming. Most Makefiles out there for building programs will break if someone adds a source file that looks like a command line option to the compiler.